# 2D Arrays - Creating virtual Creatures? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

Next, this is where it gets confusing. I have to create a virtual creature by storing a letter into a random position in the array (the array can be up to 20x20 in size). How would I go about doing that?

---

Nevermind, figured it out

Comment: So you know how to access each individual item in the 2-D array to print it, but you don't know how to do the same except compare instead of print?

Comment: Well, it's not necessarily comparing that's the confusing part, it adding the virtual creature.

Comment: After you change the type of your array from `char` to `int`, use `'0'` as the initial value; as it is a character.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't intend to provide the answer to homework, here are some commands and concepts that should help you:

- cin - to read input from the user
- rand() % number - (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/ for an example) to generate random numbers
- You will probably want to make your array of type "char" instead of "int"
- Here is a link to functions in C++ - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/
- Here is a link to operators in C++ (specifically you will want to use ==) - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

For example, to see if x is equal to y:

```
if(x == y)
{
   cout << "x equals y!";
}
```

Comment: +1 - recommending to change the array from integers to characters.